# How do I record a group donation in CiviContribute?

Tags: civicontribute

Our agency received a $867 donation from a group of unnamed individuals at an event (not connected with our agency). How do we record this donation without a contact (an individual or organization).

Answer (score 4):

It's a good question, but every contribution must be tied to a contact.  The solution is to create a generic contact called "Group donations", and add the contribution to that contact.